# Get value from dict after applying filter Jinja2

Tags: python, python-3.x, templates, jinja2

I use Jinja2 template, with dictionary. Here examples:

My dictionary:

```
context = {
    "lead":{
        "name": "Cool lead with top sale",
        "sale": 1
    },
    "contacts": [
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "tags": ['vasya']
        },
        {
            "name": "Nick Snow",
            "tags": ['petya']
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get a contact name, but only one, that has tag 'petya'. I created a filter:

```
def has_tag(entity, tagname):
    contact = list(filter(lambda x: tagname in x['tags'], entity))[0]
    return contact
```

Finally, I want to access the value in my template by something, like this:

```
{{ contacts | has_tag('petya') .name }}
```

or

```
{{ contacts | has_tag('petya') | .name }}
```

But I cannot understand - how I can do this? Because `|` uses only to filters. I cannot use **selectattr**, because there can be a lot of nested dicts, like `contacts.responsible_user.phone.mobile` etc.

Please give me advice, how I can do this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`{% set %}`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#assignments) to assign the filtered contact to a variable:

```
{% set petya = contacts | has_tag('petya') %}
{% if petya %}
  {{ petya.responsible_user.phone.mobile }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought about this. Is any way to do it in one row ?

Comment: Jinja has no concept of line breaks (aside from the `-` modifiers to elide whitespace between tags), so if you like, smoosh that `set` and `if` on the same line...

Comment: Failing that, you _could_ write your own `ifset` tag, but that's likely not going to be worth it.

Comment: Ok, and if I'll want to write my own tag, what I need to read?

Comment: The extension tutorial. It's also worth studying the existing set/if tags. https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/extensions/#module-jinja2.ext

Answer (score 0):

This: `(contacts | has_tag('petya')).responsible_user.phone.mobile` actually works as well.

For those looking for an in-line answer without defining a second variable, for cases where this does not work.